# How do I get the docker image ID of a Fargate task using the CLI/SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I want to make sure that the task is running the latest image.

Within the container, I can get the docker image ID (such as `183f9552f0a5`) by calling `http://169.254.170.2/v2/metadata`, however I am looking for a way to get it on my laptop.

Is this possible with AWS CLI or SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the Task Definition ARN for the Task using [`describe_tasks`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-tasks.html). You can skip this step if you already know the ARN.

```
aws ecs describe-tasks --tasks TASK_ARN
```

Then you can use [`describe_task_definition`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-task-definition.html) to get the image name.

```
aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition TASKDEF_ARN
```

Comment: `aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition TASKDEF_ARN | jq .taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[].image` showed the image URL like `XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/sinatra2:latest`, but what I'm looking for is the docker image ID like `183f9552f0a5`. Is it possible to obtain it?

Comment: Yes, I see now that was what you asked for. If the images are in ECR, you could use [`describe-images`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/describe-images.html) to retrieve the image ID given the repository name and tag. Other repos could offer similar APIs to retrieve the image ID as I believe it is simply a SHA digest of the image itself.

Comment: I'm using ECR, but consider this scenario:
1. push image as `latest`
2. deploy the image in ECS
3. rebuild image and push again as `latest`
4. get the image URL and SHA digest from ECS/ECR
In this case, the CLI would report the new digest. I need the exact digest of the image that ECS is running.

Comment: I think you are out of luck. I would open a feature request with AWS.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing.